# Java loss of precision with large double

Tags: java, double

```
 double lnumber = Math.pow(2, 1000);
```

prints `1.0715086071862673E301`

**Things I have tried**

I have tried to expand this number by using BigDecimal Class:

```
 String strNumber = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(lnumber)).toPlainString();
```

this just prints:

> 10715086071862673000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I also tried to use DecimalFormat:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
    String strNumber = String.valueOf(df.format(lnumber));
```

prints the same thing:

> 10715086071862673000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

The actual answer according to Wolfram Alpha is

[image]

How can I print all the actual values ?

Comment: You do realize that `double` only has like ~16 digits of precision right?

Comment: I recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: `0.0` is exact.  However for values with more than 16 digits of accuracy, some are exact but most are not.  In real world situations, 16 is more than your can measure.  Can you give a real world example of when you would need to calculate this to the accuracy you are talking about?

Comment: The double result does match the Wolfram Alpha result. The only problem was the Double.toString call which rounded the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't mix and match Math, primitive types and BigDecimal like that, if you want real precision, just use BigDecimal only:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(2);
System.out.println(value.pow(1000));
```

Comment: As a corollary, [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) also exists as a sibling to [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). They are going to be slower than primitives, but that's the cost of the higher precision.

Comment: **Why** can't you mix and match Math and primitive types, as long as you do it correctly? I often use BigDecimal to get the exact value of a float or double.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan because you can't do it correctly. If you do a single operation between floating point numbers you could already lose precision and a BigDecimal won't fix it (try to create a `BigDecimal` with the result of `1.01 + 1.17`, the result surely isn't what you would expect).

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares The exact value of the nearest double to 1.01 is 1.0100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625. The exact value of the nearest double to 1.17 is 1.1699999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875. Their sum is 2.1799999999999999378275106209912337362766265869140625. The double approximation to their sum is 2.17999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875, which shows just about the rounding error I would expect, based on my understanding of IEEE 754. This illustrates the sort of information that can be obtained by combining BigDecimal and double.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan the OP wants exact precision and I was talking about exact precision. If you're accepting rounding errors it isn't exact precision anymore and you wouldn't need BigDecimal for that anyway.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares 2**1000 is exactly representable in IEEE 754 64-bit binary. The API Javadoc for Math.pow says "If both arguments are integers, then the result is exactly equal to the mathematical result of raising the first argument to the power of the second argument if that result can in fact be represented exactly as a double value.". The double calculation was exact. The only rounding was in the conversion to String.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the actual value of a double, use the BigDecimal(double) constructor. `Double.toString(lnumber)` does rounding.

`System.out.println(new BigDecimal((Math.pow(2, 1000))))` outputs 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376

Math.pow(2,1000) is exactly representable in double, because it is a power of two that is in the representable range.